# ASP.NET MVC2 ModelMetadataProviders: What's the difference between overriding CreateMetadata() and GetMetadataForProperty()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm statring to explore the framework's extension points, starting with MetadataProviders. I've currently implemented [populating ModelMetadata.IsRequired property using `RequiredAttribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662442/asp-net-mvc-modelmetadata-is-there-a-way-to-set-isrequired-based-on-the-required) succesfully, but I can't seem to find the difference between 
overriding `CreateMetadata()` or `GetMetadataForProperty()`, since both options seem to work.

In general, the examples I've seen override `CreateMetadata()`.

- What are the pro and cons of using either options?
- Are there any scenarios where one of these are the preferred options?

As an extra: are there any good resources (blogs, books) to learn from this extension point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `GetMetadataForProperty()` is declared on the class `ModelMetadataProvider`.

`AssociatedMetadataProvider` derives from `ModelMetadataProvider`.  `CreateMetadata()` is declared on `AssociatedMetadataProvider`.  The `DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider` that is overridden in the link you provide is derived from `AssociatedMetadataProvider`.

The MVC framework makes calls to `ModelMetadataProvider`'s `GetMetadataForProperty()` method.

The reason overriding `CreateMetadata()` is working for you is because the `AssociatedModelMetadataProvider`'s default implementation of `GetMetadataForProperty()` makes a call to `CreateMetadata()`.  It looks like this:

```
public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForProperty(Func<object> modelAccessor, Type containerType, string propertyName)
{
   if (containerType == null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("containerType");
   }
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
   {
       throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "propertyName");
   }
   PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = this.GetTypeDescriptor(containerType).GetProperties().Find(propertyName, true);
   if (propertyDescriptor == null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, MvcResources.Common_PropertyNotFound, new object[] { containerType.FullName, propertyName   }));
   }
return this.GetMetadataForProperty(modelAccessor, containerType, propertyDescriptor);
```

}

```
protected virtual ModelMetadata GetMetadataForProperty(Func<object> modelAccessor, Type containerType, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) 
{
   IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes = this.FilterAttributes(containerType, propertyDescriptor, propertyDescriptor.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>());
   return this.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, propertyDescriptor.PropertyType, propertyDescriptor.Name);
}
```

If you are subclassing the `AssociatedMetadataProvider` as you are in the link you provided, then your preferred extensibility point is the `CreateMetadata` method, because the `AssociatedMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForProperty()` method pre-validates the contract of your `CreateMetadata()` method.  That way, you know that if there is an error in your `CreateMetadata()` method, you already know that the source of the error is in your method and not in the arguments that were passed to it.

Also, here is the source of the `FilterAttributes()` method, in case you were wondering:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<Attribute> FilterAttributes(Type containerType, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
{
if (!typeof(ViewPage).IsAssignableFrom(containerType) && !typeof(ViewUserControl).IsAssignableFrom(containerType))
    {
        return attributes;
    }
    return attributes.Where<Attribute>(delegate (Attribute a) {
        return !(a is ReadOnlyAttribute);
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the complete answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to award the bounty to you, but forgot to actually do it. I'll add antoher one and accept it tomorrow. Fair is fair.